# Python.h: El fichero o directorio no existe

Tags: python, c++

Estoy intentando llamar desde C++ a Python para eso necesito incluir la libreria `Python.h`

El problema es que cuando lo hago, me tira error de archivo on encontrado. Estoy usando Visual Studio Code, tengo instalado el MinGW tambien, las rutas C:\MinGW , C:\Python38, tengo las rutas respectivas agregadas al path también.

¿Alguno me podría orientar a como solucionarlo por favor?

```
main.cpp:2:20: error fatal: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Con que comando estas compilando? Estas añadiendo el include path?

Comment: No deberías añadir al path la ruta del incluye que hay dentro de Python? Algo como C:/Python38/include